# Deleting a Row in Table- Best way to also delete all rows it affects?

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have created a very simple `SQL` script (see below) that deletes rows in my table if a column name is a certain value.

```
DELETE FROM table_name
 WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

However, this table also enters data to *other tables* in my Database: For example it's `ID (Primary Key).`

How can I also delete the rows in the other tables?

Comment: I think you are looking for cascading foreign key references.  You can declare the references so they get updated or deleted in the tables where they are used.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a good tutorial for this?

Comment: Please dont cross post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128395/deleting-a-row-in-table-best-way-to-also-delete-all-rows-it-affects http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend a stored procedure in the database to do your delete.  Not only can you do the delete in the proper constraint order but you have the added benefit of not having to grant delete permission on the table - only execute permission on the proc.

Answer (score 0):

Like said @Gordon, 
Add a foreign key to your `table_name` and ask for `cascade_on_delete`

or

`DELETE table1, table2 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column=table2.column AND table1.column = someValue`

...Not sure about the correct synthax but that will work.

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow deleting from multiple tables in one statement.